# UITableView Couldn't fetch from Core Data on first launch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, asynchronous

So I built an app to read some JSON data from a Web API. Then it parses the JSON and store the result into Core Data. In `viewDidLoad` of my `UITableViewController` I tried to read JSON and save the result to Core Data. Then in `viewWillAppear`  I tried to fetch the data from Core Data and save it to users array.

```
//parse JSON and save result to CoreData
let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

person.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary([...])

do {
    try managedContext.save()
    users.append(person)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    fetchData()        
}

// fetch from Core Data and save to users array
class func fetchData() {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")

    do {
        let res = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        users = res as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

// code for refreshing
func refresh() {
    if isConnectedToNetwork() {
        // run some code to read newest data from Web
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
}
```

Now I have this really weird problem that when the app is launched for the first time(on both simulators and my iPhone), the tableview is always empty (but it will be populated with data after refreshing through pulling down). But when I try to build and run it again everything will look OK. 
Notice that I have tried adding `self.tableView.reloadData()` to both `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` and both inside a `dispatch_async` block and outside.
Can somebody please tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your app for the first time in your viewDidLoad you laid data from url and parse and then insert in core data meanwhile in your viewWillAppear will already called as your data is not still inserted in core data so you will see empty tableview.
You can call fetchData() and self.tableView.reloadData() after you insert the data, for the first time run fix.

Comment: could you be more specific? such as where to put fetchData()?

Comment: just put your fetchData() after you insert in core data . As you didn't post that code so I can't be more specific. Also this is only for the first time run as if the data is downloaded the you can call  fetchData() from viewdidload so you can use some flag

Comment: I tried what I thought you meant - calling fetchData() right after saving to core data but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you take a look at the project? Thanks a lot  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5swax001qjq0vtd/AABV5Z9h8hSQUOW39krD-Shma?dl=0

Comment: Its wired in your code even on refresh you are fetching data from server?
When view appears you are fetching from server. then whats the point saving on core data?
Also you need to implement callback for fetchData so you can reload your tableview in your view controller .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95240/discussion-between-kingj-and-imran).